# Distinct eigevalues and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

If $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ with $k$ distinct eigenvalues, does this imply that the minimal polynomial of $\mathbf{A}$ has degree at least $k$?

I'm aware that every eigenvalue is a root of the minimal polynomial, hence it seems that this should be true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly, for the reason you stated.